# no static method 'getContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I have problem in 'getContext()'  method is not  acceptable and does not work , and the 'ViewGroup' in the same line is "Expression expected " 
this is some code :

From My Module app

my library versions

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

My Code :

````
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =

                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout,ViewGroup, false);
public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout ,ViewGroup, false);
                        PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;


                    }
                };
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Did you search this site to see whether anyone else had had any problems accessing non-static methods from a static context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: I have problem , can u take look ?? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072702/cannot-reslove-symbol-viewholder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)