# cannot reslove symbol 'viewHolder'

Tags: java, android

Can not resolve symbol 'viewHolder'....And when I change it to 'holder' nothing is changed ...
 this is part of my code (the Custom Class)

My code :

```
private void DisplayAllUsersPosts() {


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =

                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(Posts.class, R.layout.all_posts_layout, PostsViewHolder.class, PostsRef) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {


                        viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                        viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                        viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                        viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                        viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
                        viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
                        PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;


                    }
                };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "holder" by "viewHolder" in the parameter of onBindViewHolder().

```
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {


                    viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                    viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                    viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                    viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                    viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
                    viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());

                }
```

And set values to adapter as below

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(yourList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and make separate java file for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Dont write it in function.

Comment: he told me '  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot applied  '

Comment: His suggestion is correct. You have to set adapter from your activity immediately 
 after the calling RecyclerAdapterClass.

Comment: can I give you the class code and you change it for me pleas .. ?\

Comment: have a look on this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/  . You will get to know everything.

Comment: this line is red "(Posts.class, R.layout.all_posts_layout, PostsViewHolder.class, PostsRef)" give an error

Answer (score -1):

```java
private void DisplayAllUsersPosts() {
  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(Posts.class, R.layout.all_posts_layout, PostsViewHolder.class, PostsRef) {
      @Override
      protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
        holder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
        holder.setTime(model.getTime());
        holder.setDate(model.getDate());
        holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
        holder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
        holder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());
      }

      @NonNull
      @Override
      public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
        PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
      }
    };
  postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: this line is red "(Posts.class, R.layout.all_posts_layout, PostsViewHolder.class, PostsRef)" give an error : 
" FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied "